# Удалить ненужные методы

Tags: visual-studio

Как удалить из класса методы, которые нигде не используются? По аналогии с IntelliSence которая удаляет ненужные `using`, но удалить те методы в классе которые были описаны но ни разу не вызваны. Можно ли такое сделать в VS?

Comment: Какое-то слишком деструктивное действие...

Comment: а если они потом когда-нибудь вызовутся? В частности, из-за рефлексии и expression tree, нельзя гарантировать, что метод не вызывается нигде

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Delll указано `ссылок: 0` - означает что никто на эту функцию не ссылается. Её можно удалить. Но иногда Visual Studio не понимает ссылок, если функции используются по особому. Удалять такие можно но без 100% гарантий.

При нажатии на `ссылок` отобразятся функции вызывающие текущую.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня нет строки : `ссылка:1 | 0 изменений | 0 авторов...`

Comment: Какая версия Visual Studio? Enterprise или Professional? Это называется CodeLens https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn269218.aspx

Comment: У меня 2015 Community

Comment: Или поставь другую версию (Требуется: Visual Studio Enterprise или Visual Studio Professional) или поищи какое-нибудь альтернативное расширение

Comment: это не поможет, если функция будет вызываться через рефлексию

Comment: @Grundy т.е. единственное решение это все проверять вручную ?

Comment: @Сергей, в принципе полнотекстовый поиск по проекту может чуть помочь, но если есть публичная функция, в которую передается имя метода, то ничего не поможет, так как в нее можно передать имя _любого_ метода